# How can I convert AnyClass<T> to AnyClass<BaseClassOfT> implicitly/Without recreating an object

Tags: c#, generics, casting, implicit-conversion, covariance

I have a context in which I do not know what the specific type of my viewModel is, however, I have a base type of the viewModels.

How would I convert my `SomeClass<T>` to `SomeClass<BaseOfT>` without recreating the object?

My signature of `SomeClass` is `SomeClass<T> where T : BaseOfT`

When using `as` or implicit operators it will cause a runtime error (or produce `null` in case of `as`ofc).

Comment: Just because two types, `A` and `B` have a particular inheritance relationship, that does not mean that `G<A>` and `G<B>` have that *same* relationship.

Comment: but T is always of type BaseOfT, ins't it? I can always cast T to BaseOfT

Comment: Does the signature of `SomeClass` look like `public class SomeClass<T> where T : BaseOfT`

Comment: yes it is, Ill add that to the question

Comment: You can always go from most derived class to the base class, but you can't go the other way round. So you can have `List<T>`  and cast to `List<BaseOfT>` but you can't go the other way round

Comment: @CallumLinington How would I cast my `SomeClass<T>` to `SomeClass<BaseOfT>` then? Thats my question

Comment: Does some class have a property that is `T` so like `public T Data {get;set;}`

Comment: Yes, In my example it has `T DialogViewModel { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Consider the following example, which shows why "`A` is a subtype of `B`" does not imply "`T<A>` is a subtype of `T<B>`":

```
List<object> myListOfObjects = (List<object>)myListOfCats;
myListOfObjects.Add(new Dog());
```

You can, however, create [covariant interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) by using the [`out` generic modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) in the interface declaration:

```
ISomeInterface<BaseClassOfT> a = new SomeClass<T>();
```

Comment: Alright, thank you! It makes sense in the end. I'll have to find another way for solving my problem then, because this wasn't the correct approach apparently